# 403 Error when adding contacts to sendgrid

Tags: laravel, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm using then Sendgrid's account trial and used API key that has full access. I also referred to this documentation [doc](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/main/USAGE.md#contactdb)
[image]

This is always the results

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found it.

You should use Guzzle and this API: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact.